# Наименование соуса, поставленное в именительном падеже

Tags: пунктуация

Картофель с соусом говяжий - встретил такое предложение без знаков препинания на ценнике в супермаркете.

Насколько оно корректно, допустимо?

Answer (score 1):

**Не корректно.**
Очевидно, что говяжий именно соус, а не картофель.
Правильно так: *картофель с говяжьим соусом*.

Либо *говяжий* — название соуса. Тогда нужны кавычки: *картофель с соусом "Говяжий"*.

Примечание: если этот соус — единица товара, который можно купить отдельно, то кавычки нужны; если просто с таким соусом, то лучше прилагательное в творительном падеже.

Comment: Извините, мягкий знак не потеряли? Правильно: с говяжьим соусом.

Comment: ОК. Исправлено.

Answer (score 0):

Если это указание на *тип* соуса (что наиболее вероятно), то нарицательное наименование *говяжий* должно быть в творительном падеже; если же указывается конкретный продукт (соус, на этикетке которого значится "Говяжий", и это можно объяснить посетителю, либо соус под таким наименованием предлагается отдельно, напр. в разделе меню о соусах), то *возможно* написание в именительном падеже, но обязательно в кавычках (с соусом "Говяжий"). В обоих случаях естественнее первый вариант.